# Why --audit commands does not work in Mongo Enterprise

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to make destination for my user activity log but every time I type --auditDestination I get errormessage "unrecognized option --auditDestination", can anyone tell me what should I do?

I really need a help with this, if anyone can help with some solution I will be grateful :/

Comment: What version of Mongo, what OS, and what are you trying to use as the destination?

Comment: I'm using Mongo Enterprise on Win 10 and I'm trying to put JSON audit file in folder on my C disc

Comment: @JoDi, Could you elaborate bit more , what you are writing syntax for '--auditDestination' in MongoDB Enterprise 'mongod' server or 'configuration file' .

Comment: Specifically, I want to put user activity log in one json file on my computer (c disc) and I'm trying to run command from Windows PowerShell, like this: "mongod --dbpath data/db --auditDestination file --auditFormat JSON --auditPath data/db/auditLog.json"

Answer (score 0):

`--auditDestination` is parameter of mongoD and mongoS, if you try to use it with `mongo` command, you get error message.

Comment: I know that and I tried with both mongoD and mongoS but nothing :(

Comment: It must be that windows.. I have linux enterprise 3.4 and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

@JoDi, as you said your environment is windows and you want to `--auditDestination` in 'c:\' .

As per MongoDB BOL [Configure Auditing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-auditing/) To enable auditing and print audit events to a file in `JSON` format, specify file for the `--auditDestination` setting, `JSON` for the `--auditFormat` setting, and the output filename for the `--auditPath`. The `--auditPath` option accepts either full path name or relative path name. For example, the following enables auditing and records audit events to a file with the relative path name of `data/db/auditLog.json`:

```
mongod --dbpath data/db --auditDestination file --auditFormat JSON --auditPath data/db/auditLog.json
```

> As here **dbpath** is C:\data\db  , **file** is the destination file location 
>   & **AuditPath** is C:\data\db\auditLog.json

You may also specify these options in the `configuration file`:

```
storage:
   dbPath: data/db
auditLog:
   destination: file
   format: JSON
   path: data/db/auditLog.json
```

> **NOTE** Printing audit events to a file in JSON format degrades server
>   performance more than printing to a file in BSON format.

Comment: Thank you for replaying, I did everything what did you say but the problem is that when I type any of this (--auditDestination, --auditFormat...) I'm getting error message that this options didn't recognised